# Do you have to pay capital gains tax when selling and immediately buying another cryptocurrency in US?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, exchanges

Is it possible to convert eg. BTC to ETH and pay capital gains tax only when you sell and convert crypto into USD?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to report the tax if I trade BTC to LTC?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56597/how-to-report-the-tax-if-i-trade-btc-to-ltc)

Comment: No, it's outdated, 4 years ago.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bitcoin.stackexchange is not the appropriate place to ask about taxstion questions (especially when OP doesn't even mention which jurisdiction they reside in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/frequently-asked-questions-on-virtual-currency-transactions

(Retrieved 2022-03-16)

> Q16.  Will I recognize a gain or loss if I exchange my virtual currency for other property?
>
> A16.  Yes.  If you exchange virtual currency held as a capital asset for other property, including for goods or for another virtual currency, you will recognize a capital gain or loss.  For more information on capital gains and capital losses, see Publication 544, Sales and Other Dispositions of Assets.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, any *sell* event is a taxable event. Even if that event is converting a crypto.